# (Local) simple connectedness of irreducible algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $\mathbb k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

I have two questions:

(1) Is an irreducible algebraic variety $X/\mathbb k$ of dimension at least 2 locally simply connected?

(2) Let $X/\mathbb k$ be an irreducible algebraic variety and $Y$ a closed subvariety of dimension at least 2. If $X$ is (locally) simply connected, is $X\setminus Y$ (locally) simply connected?

Comment: Please define "locally simply connected". For which topology?

Comment: Zariski topology.

Comment: For any Zariski open subset $U\subset X$, the homomorphism $\pi _1(U)\rightarrow \pi _1(X)$ is surjective. So if $X$ is not simply connected, $U$ is not either.

Comment: Yeah, but question (2) goes the other way around: if $X$ is simply connected, is the open subset $X\setminus Y$ simply connected?

Comment: Yes, if you mean that $Y$ has *codimension* $\geq 2$. Removing a closed subvariety of codimension at least 2 doesn't change $\pi_1$.

Comment: For question (1) the answer is no (I mean *never*), as soon as $\dim(X)>0$. For each point $x\in X$ you can  find $f\in \mathscr{O}_{X,x}^\times$ which is not a square. Then (assuming $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{k})\neq2$) $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{X,x}[\sqrt{f}])$ extends to a nontrivial étale cover of some neighborhood $U$ of $x$, so $U$ is not simply connected.